# INSERT com informações de um banco de dados dentro de outro banco de dados C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estou tentando fazer uma aplicação onde eu consiga fazer backup de vários bancos ao mesmo tempo colocando as informações dos bancos (que será feito o backup) dentro de um banco que alocará essas informações.

Mas não consigo colocar as informações por um erro de sintaxe, poderiam me ajudar dizendo o que há de errado na sintaxe?

```
        private void cadastroButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dataBaseBox.CheckedItems.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Por favor selecione um Banco de Dados.");
                return;
            }

            else
            {
                foreach (var check in dataBaseBox.CheckedItems)
                {
                    cn = new SqlConnection(connString2());
                    cn.Open();
                    string query;
                    query = "INSERT INTO bancos(nome,diretorio,hora) VALUES = '" + check.ToString() + "','"+horarioBox+"' + '"+locationTextBox.Text + "'";
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(query,cn);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cn.Close();

                }

            }
            MessageBox.Show("Backup executado com sucesso!");

        }
```

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Na verdade o erro mesmo é que isto é inseguro, um dos motivos de dar o erro. Claro que fazendo certo pode causar erro, mas pelo menos ajuda evitar. Pesquise aqui mesmo sobre isso, Veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/183986/101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O correto é:

```
"INSERT INTO bancos(nome,diretorio,hora) VALUES ('" + check.ToString() + "','"+horarioBox+"' + '"+locationTextBox.Text + "');";
```

e não

```
VALUES = 'TESTE','TESTE','TESTE'
```

ps. Prefira por usar parâmetros nos comandos, veja: http://www.devmedia.com.br/utilizando-parametros-no-sqlcommand-em-c/28440

Comment: Era isto mesmo! @Rovann, obrigado!