# Erro ao concatenar valor do componente em query

Tags: c#, string, query, ado.net, concatenação-de-string

As *queries* em meu projeto C# Winforms estão sendo realizadas através de `StringBuilder`. Foi sugerido aqui no SO que eu alterasse a forma de gerar a *query* de `Consulta.Append("Select * from...")` para `@"select * from..."` por ser algo redundante. Segue abaixo um fragmento do código após a alteração:

```
string Consulta = @"select nome as Nome,  
       endereco as Endereço,
       telefone as Telefone,
       dataCadastro as [Data de Cadastro]
    From clientes
       where dataCadastro='"+ Convert.toString(dePeriodo.Text) +"'
       and status<>0";
foreach (DataRow iRow in Dados.SQLData.dsData(Consulta).Tables[0].Rows)
  {
     //restante aqui
  }
```

Acontece que ao utilizar o método informado não é possível concatenar o parâmetro do componente `DateEdit (dePeriodo)` pois as aspas duplas que está em `...dataCadastro='"+ dePeriodo...`, qual abre a concatenação, na verdade está fechando a *query*. Como devo proceder para concatenar o valor do componente com a *query* sem ocasionar este erro?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

Imaginando que está usando um `Command` o correto é fazer isto:

```
comando.CommandText = @"select nome as Nome,  
        endereco as Endereço,
        telefone as Telefone,
        dataCadastro as [Data de Cadastro]
    from clientes
    where dataCadastro = @Periodo and status<>'0'";
comando.Parameters.Add("@Periodo", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = dePeriodo.Text;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/Query.cs).

Não posso garantir que seja exatamente isto porque não tenho todas informações necessárias, mas é mais ou menos isso.

Ou poderia ser isto:

```
comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Periodo", dePeriodo.Text));
```

Se não fizer desta forma terá problema de segurança por injeção de SQL, um problema que deve afetar uns 90% dos sites porque hoje a maioria das pessoas não aprendem antes de fazer. Não use a interpolação de *string* como mostrada na outra resposta. Um exemplo mais completo em [Alguma solução do ASP.NET MVC para injeção SQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183975/101).

Comment: @Manieiro, mesmo para preencher um `DataSet` ?

Comment: Qualquer consulta ao banco de dados que tenha parâmteros.

Answer (score 0):

Só tirar as aspas simples do `0` (zero).

```
string Consulta = @"select nome as Nome,  
   endereco as Endereço,
   telefone as Telefone,
   dataCadastro as [Data de Cadastro]
From clientes
   where dataCadastro='"+ Convert.toString(dePeriodo.Text) +"'
   and status<> 0 ";

foreach (DataRow iRow in Dados.SQLData.dsData(Consulta).Tables[0].Rows)
{
   //restante aqui
}
```

Comment: Bem observado Marcelo, mas na verdade esse foi um erro de cópia meu... eu simplifiquei a consulta pq a original tem 78 linhas

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver utilizando o Framework core, mais recente poderá fazer assim:

```
string Consulta = $@"select nome as Nome,  
           endereco as Endereço,
           telefone as Telefone,
           dataCadastro as [Data de Cadastro]
        From clientes
           where dataCadastro='{Convert.toString(dePeriodo.Text)}'
           and status<> 0 ";

        foreach (DataRow iRow in Dados.SQLData.dsData(Consulta).Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            //restante aqui
        }
```

A concatenação acontece como o string.format.

O caso que para evitar SQL Injection, deve-se fazer como o Maniero disse mesmo. É a forma mais segura de se trabalhar.