# Erro ao salvar valores monetários no banco de dados MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Tenho uma coluna da tabela do meu banco chamada `salario_base` onde a mesma é do tipo `Decimal(7,2)`. Insiro o valor em uma `textbox`, converto o mesmo e passo essa e outras variáveis para uma classe de inserção completar essa operação. Os demais dados estão sendo perfeitamente salvos, porém o salário não. Segue exemplo do que estou tentando salvar no banco:

**Ex:** *1500.65*

Tento realizar a inserção demonstrada no exemplo acima, no entanto é salvo apenas o valor *1500.00*, quando não uso o "."(ponto), salva *150065.00*

a variável está declarada na aplicação como uma variável do tipo decimal. *Edit.* 
**Segue o código:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using Sistema_RH.Classes;
using Sistema_RH.FORMULARIOS;
using Sistema_RH.NEGOCIOS;

namespace Sistema_RH.DADOS
{
    public class DAOFolhadePagamento
    {
        public void CadastrarPayment(string rsocial, string cnpj, string nomefunc, decimal sbase, string depart, string obs)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection connectaInBD = DAOConexao.getConnection())
                try
                {   
                    string RazaoSocial = rsocial;
                    string CNPJ = cnpj;
                    string NomeFuncionario = nomefunc;
                    decimal SalarioBase = sbase;
                    string Departamento = depart;
                    string Observacoes = obs;

                    string ComandoSQL = "INSERT INTO folhadepagamento (razao_social, cnpj, nome_do_funcionario, salario_base, departamento, observacoes)" +
                    " VALUES (@razao_social, @cnpj, @nome_do_funcionario, @salario_base, @departamento, @observacoes)";


                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ComandoSQL);

                    connectaInBD.Open();
                    MySqlCommand inserttDados = new MySqlCommand(ComandoSQL, connectaInBD);

                    inserttDados.Parameters.Add("@razao_social", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                    inserttDados.Parameters.Add("@cnpj", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
                    inserttDados.Parameters.Add("@nome_do_funcionario", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                    inserttDados.Parameters.Add("@salario_base", MySqlDbType.Decimal, 12);
                    inserttDados.Parameters.Add("@departamento", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    inserttDados.Parameters.Add("@observacoes", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 500);

                    inserttDados.Parameters["@razao_social"].Value = RazaoSocial;
                    inserttDados.Parameters["@cnpj"].Value = CNPJ;
                    inserttDados.Parameters["@nome_do_funcionario"].Value = NomeFuncionario;
                    inserttDados.Parameters["@salario_base"].Value = SalarioBase;
                    inserttDados.Parameters["@departamento"].Value = Departamento;
                    inserttDados.Parameters["@observacoes"].Value = Observacoes;

                    inserttDados.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }

                finally
                {
                    connectaInBD.Close();
                } 
        }

    }
}
```

**Edit2:** realizei as modificações que me foram sugeridas nos comentários. Porém o valor ainda não está sendo guardado no banco da forma que queria que fosse(como exposto no início). Resolvi insolar a `textbox` referente a entrada desse valor e chapei o valor direto na variável `Salario_Base`.
 Segue exemplo:
**Ex.:** `decimal SalarioBase = 1500.55M;` esse **M** foi o próprio Visual Studio que sugeriu,
 dessa maneira a inserção ocorreu e o valor foi salvo como esperado no banco.
Pensei em usar o método `Concat(txtSalarioBase.Text, "M");`e depois usar o `Convert.ToDecimal();`. [Porém parece que não funciona](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25461431/convert-todecimal-does-not-work-with-string-9-02), logo nem sequer tentei implementar, estou seguindo as instruções do link acima. Realmente não sei o que fazer...

Comment: mostre o seu código

Comment: Aqui não é um fórum, se você leu para usar `Replace()`, lamento, a gente tentou fazer as respostas terem qualidade, mas as que ensinaram fazer isto,ensinaram errado (a não ser que tenha um contexto que eu não estou sabendo). Na verdade já tem um erro conceitual aí. Mas sem o código sequer podemos afalar muito, menos ainda ajudar.

Comment: @Maniero adicionei o código.

Comment: Não tem nada de decimal, de salário nele. Vi vários outros erros no código.

Comment: @Maniero agora está certo, anteriormente tinha copiado e colado a classe errada.

Comment: E se você fizer certo e tirar o grave problema de segurança do seu código, o erro continua? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104614/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183975/101

Comment: NÃO experimenta, repito, NÃO preencha o campo `Observações` com o seguinte texto `'); TRUNCATE TABLE folhadepagamento; --`

Comment: Eu acabei alterando como o @Maniero me sugeriu, a mudança seguirá nessa pergunta com as alterações sofridas!

Answer (score 0):

O código abaixo não é tão elegante, mas acho que ajuda:

`string ammount = (textBox2.Text).Replace (",",".");`

e eu insiro o valor como string. Quando o valor é passado para a instrução sql:

```
string initialquery = "INSERT INTO EXPENSES (ID, E_DATE, AMMOUNT, PERSON, COMMENTS, T_ID) " +
                                "VALUES ('" + id + "', '" + date.ToString("yyyy:MM:dd") + "', '" + ammount + "', '" + person + "', '" + comments + "', '" + tid + "')";
```

Original:
[c# mysql decimal numbers with . or ,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959482/c-sharp-mysql-decimal-numbers-with-or/10966991#10966991)